# Receiving "Access Denied" when attempting to read group files

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Trying to retrieve files for an MS Team with the following query:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/drive
… but I am receiving "Access Denied"

I have made sure to grant the following permissions (and then some):
Files.Read, Files.ReadWrite, Files.Read.All, Files.ReadWrite.All, Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All

I am simply trying to list the files. Am I using the wrong API call? What other permissions do I need to grant? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions required for each operation/entity are listed on the documentation page.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: The permissions granted above *are* the ones that are described in the documentation.

Comment: Group.Read.All ?

Comment: Yes, the **Group.Read.All** permission has been granted. I can list the channels in the group, which also requires Group.Read.All. Thanks.

Comment: Crazy thing is that I can't access files by group, but I **can** retrieve drives with https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives